# adding unique rows to a dataframe out of memory

Tags: r

I have `my_data_base` initial data in a dataframe where the first column is the `name` and the subsequent columns are the logs. For simplicity, I made a small example with five logical columns, in real data there are about a thousand columns

```
set.seed(1)
make_dat <- function(nrow=1, ncol=5) {
  cbind.data.frame(name=stringi::stri_rand_strings(n=nrow, length=3), 
                   matrix(data=sample(c(T, F), nrow*ncol, T), ncol=ncol))
}
my_data_base <- make_dat(nrow=10, ncol=5)
```

..

```
my_data_base

   name     1     2     3     4     5
1   GNZ FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
2   uCt FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
3   wed  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
4   3CA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
5   gNl  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
6   Uiz  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
7   Nmv FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
8   De7  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
9   GN0 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
10  NrL FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Also I have new data that comes in as a new row

```
new_data <- make_dat(nrow=1, ncol=5)
```

..

```
 new_data
  name    1    2     3    4     5
1  QiO TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

The essence of my algorithm is very simple.
When `new_data` arrives, I check if the `new_data` is unique with respect to the rows in  `my_data_base`. If so, then a new row is added, if not, then everything remains as is.

```
for (i in 1:100) {
  new_data <- make_dat(nrow=1, ncol=5)
  is_unique_new_data <- all(apply(my_data_base[, -1], 1, \(row) 
                                  all(new_data[, -1] == row)) == FALSE)
  if (is_unique_new_data) my_data_base <- rbind.data.frame(my_data_base, new_data)
}
```

The problem is that the size of `my_data_base` is growing very quickly and I would like to find a way to keep and grow `my_data_base` out of memory, given that I need to check for the uniqueness of a new row.

In what ways can this be done?
Perhaps this can be done using an `arrow` or `polars` or a `database` or the standard capabilities of `R` or something else?

Comment: It appears you have a conundrum: iteratively adding rows to a frame will eventually scale very poorly (see "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)), but tests of "data A matches a row in data B" lose efficiency if you choose to maintain a list of frames. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, `apply(df, 1, ..)` is incurring the penalty of casting all number to strings (a minimal computation effort but a huge cost in memory), adding to the inefficiency of iterative binding. It's still necessary to not `rbind` every time, but this is making it a little worse.

Comment: Your question is about out-of-memory processing using R tools, which means (to me) something like a database or `arrow` parquet files. The latter (parquet files) are immutable, which means once you "save" so-many-rows, if you want to add a new row you create a new file, and `arrow`'s data connection transparently combines multiple files into one apparent data source (assuming identical schema). Unfortunately, as you get to many many more 1-row files, it slows a little, at which point one should consider combining files. I suspect a database is far better for this.

Comment: why are you deleting what I believe to be still-relevant comments?

Comment: As far as I remember, I didn’t delete anything at all

Comment: Interesting, okay, sorry, I thought for sure my comments were were replies or had your replies against them. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I didn’t receive a notification at all that you answered me yesterday, I only now see your answer. Some kind of glitch or something

Comment: Make sure to read @IanGow's comments at the end of my answer. I haven't tested it, but it seems like the `maybe_add_row_sql` function might be dplyr-ized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Complete rewrite.*

I believe you are trying to insert guaranteed-unique rows into a dataset. The previous version of my answer did that, but it was all in-memory. In R, when talking about out-of-memory dataset, there are several ways that work, but not many that work *well* with repeated addition of data.

Up front: having column names of `1`, `2`, etc is *evil*, both for R and for databases. Many `DBI`-related tools do not do a good job of protecting against having a column name of `1`, so I *strongly* urge you to reconsider those names. For this demonstration, I'll just `v1`, `v2`, etc.

As such, the function and initial data will be:

```r
set.seed(1)
make_dat <- function(nrow=1, ncol=5) {
  out <- cbind.data.frame(name=stringi::stri_rand_strings(n=nrow, length=3), 
                          matrix(data=sample(c(T, F), nrow*ncol, T), ncol=ncol))
  colnames(out)[-1] <- paste0("v", colnames(out)[-1])
  out
}
my_data_base <- make_dat(nrow=10, ncol=5)
head(my_data_base, 2)
#   name    v1    v2    v3    v4    v5
# 1  GNZ FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# 2  uCt FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

---

I have two quick methods: (1) a "proper" database; and (2) a CSV check/append hack.

The biggest differences I can think of:

- The CSV hack method can only work on one row at a time, so your `nrow=` argument may need to be hard-coded to 1, or you will iterate over each row in `new_data`. This will slow it down even more.
- If you at some point say "insert even if column XYZ is the same", then the CSV hack does not easily permit this (though it is further hackable, I do not recommend it).

### CSV hack

This is a little bit of a hack but if you aren't looking for something formal, this might work well enough. For this, you can write the initial `my_data_base` into a CSV, and then each row can be *appended* (`header=FALSE`, just the data) to the file only if `grep -q` (command-line) indicates the row does not already exist.

```
Once you want to _use_ the data, I'd go with `arrow::read_csv_arrow(.., as_data_frame=FALSE)` and `dplyr` processing, which allows lazy filtering/querying with a simple `%>% collect()` at the end where filtered data is finally brought into memory.
```

Two commands: "check" and "append".

For "check", we'll use `write.table` to create what the line should look like, and `grep -q` it against the file, returning a status code of `0` if it is found, `1` if it is not.

For "append", we'll take the text that `write.table` created and just append it to the file.

Demonstration of the concept and components:

```r
### works on only one row at a time, though it can
### be modified/extended to work on multiple rows at
### the expense of performance/efficiency
maybe_add_row <- function(x, file) {
  ### CHECK
  txt <- capture.output(write.table(x, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, sep=","))
  res <- processx::run("grep", args = c("-q", txt, file), error_on_status = FALSE)
  if (res$status == 1) {
    ### APPEND
    cat(txt, "\n", file = file, append = TRUE)
    TRUE
  } else FALSE
}

### initial file creation
dbfn <- "mydata.csv"
write.csv(my_data_base, dbfn, row.names=FALSE)
processx::run("wc", c("-l", dbfn))$stdout   # verify number of lines in the file
# [1] "11 mydata.csv\n"

new_data <- my_data_base[3,]       # will be the same, should not be inserted
maybe_add_row_csv(new_data, dbfn)  # should not be added
# [1] FALSE
processx::run("wc", c("-l", dbfn))$stdout
# [1] "11 mydata.csv\n"

new_data$v1 <- (!new_data$v1)      # will be different, should be inserted
maybe_add_row_csv(new_data, dbfn)  # should be added
# [1] TRUE
processx::run("wc", c("-l", dbfn))$stdout
# [1] "12 mydata.csv\n"
```

Now that we have that verified, we can iterate and go with it. In this loop, I'll add a `runif(1)` to randomly choose to put in a known-existing file, just to prove the point.

```r
print(processx::run("wc", c("-l", dbfn))$stdout)
# [1] "12 mydata.csv\n"
system.time({
  for (i in 1:100) {
    new_data <-
      if (runif(1) < 0.1) {
        message("forcing a dupe!")
        my_data_base[sample(nrow(my_data_base), 1),]
      } else make_dat(nrow=1, ncol=5)
    res <- maybe_add_row_csv(new_data, dbfn)
    if (!res) message(".. not inserted")
  }
  print(processx::run("wc", c("-l", dbfn))$stdout)
})
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# [1] "97 mydata.csv\n"
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.265  13.760  13.925 
print(processx::run("wc", c("-l", dbfn))$stdout)
# [1] "97 mydata.csv\n"
```

*This is not fast!* That operation took 14 seconds, clearly repeatedly calling `grep` is going to be a problem. (Mind you, don't try to use R's `grep(readLines(..))`, on that, you're defeating the purpose of out-of-memory operation.)

From here, we can lazily read *some* of the data into memory using `arrow` and `dplyr`.

```r
library(arrow)
library(dplyr)
arr <- arrow::read_csv_arrow(dbfn, as_data_frame = FALSE)
arr
# Table
# 96 rows x 6 columns
# $name <string>
# $v1 <bool>
# $v2 <bool>
# $v3 <bool>
# $v4 <bool>
# $v5 <string>
nrow(arr)
# [1] 96
arr %>%
  filter(grepl("a", name)) %>%
  collect()
# # A tibble: 3 × 6
#   name  v1    v2    v3    v4    v5      
#   <chr> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <chr>   
# 1 a9L   FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE "TRUE " 
# 2 XYa   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE "FALSE "
# 3 xha   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE "FALSE "
```

`filter` (and `mutate`, etc) supports many R expressions but definitely not many arbitrary ones; it'll tell you clearly if it does not support, but when doing so it might try to read it into memory anyway, so be mindful. A safe technique would be to do `arr %>% head() %>% filter(something_crazy)`, and if it cannot do the direct translation, it will only pull in 6 rows (obviously remove `head()` once you've verified that the expressions work. Read https://arrow.apache.org/docs/2.0/r/articles/dataset.html for more information on this.

### "Proper" database

We can do a SQL "anti-join" on the new data against the existing data, only inserting those rows that to not already appear.

```r
library(duckdb) # if you have another, feel free to adapt to that
### you will probably want a non-temp file
tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".duckdb")
db <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), tf)

tbl <- "mydata"
tmptbl <- "mydata_temp"
dbWriteTable(db, tbl, my_data_base)
dbWriteTable(db, tmptbl, my_data_base[0,]) # create empty table
dbGetQuery(db, sprintf("select * from %s limit 3", tbl))
#   name    v1    v2    v3    v4    v5
# 1  GNZ FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# 2  uCt FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# 3  wed  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

The "anti-join" is a simple concept, similar to a regular left-join but returning data only when one side is (all) null. I'll demonstrate a test checking if all fields are null, though if you know that one field (`name` for instance) will never be `NA` in R or `null` in the db, then you can limit the `where` clause to just one field for some SQL efficiency.

```r
cns <- colnames(my_data_base)
antijoin_sql <- 
  sprintf("
    select t1.* 
    from %s t1 left join %s t2 on %s
    where %s", tmptbl, tbl,
    paste(sprintf("t1.%s=t2.%s", cns, cns), collapse = " and "),
    paste(sprintf("t2.%s is null", cns), collapse = " and "))

### clearly this is all duplicated
cns <- colnames(my_data_base)
new_data <- my_data_base[3,]
new_data
#   name   v1   v2    v3    v4   v5
# 3  wed TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE
dbWriteTable(db, tmptbl, new_data, append=T)

### change one field in the temp table
dbExecute(db, sprintf("update %s set v1=not v1", tmptbl))
# [1] 1
dbGetQuery(db, antijoin_sql)
#   name    v1   v2    v3    v4   v5
# 1  wed FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

We'll change the `antijoin_sql` so that it will insert into the target table those rows that aren't found. Recall that the current state of the data in `tmptbl` is that it *does not match* (since we changed the `name`), so we expect the first `maybe_add_row_sql` to succeed.

```r
maybe_add_row_sql <- function(x, con, tbl, tmptbl) {
  cns <- colnames(x)
  antijoin_sql <- 
    sprintf("
      insert into %s
      select t1.* 
      from %s t1 left join %s t2 on %s
      where %s", tbl, tmptbl, tbl,
    paste(sprintf("t1.%s=t2.%s", cns, cns), collapse = " and "),
    paste(sprintf("t2.%s is null", cns), collapse = " and "))
  dbWriteTable(db, tmptbl, x, append = TRUE)
  on.exit(
    try(dbExecute(db, paste("delete from", tmptbl)), silent = TRUE),
    add = TRUE)
  dbExecute(db, antijoin_sql)
}
dbGetQuery(db, paste("select count(*) as n from", tbl))
#    n
# 1 10
maybe_add_row_sql(my_data_base[1,], db, tbl, tmptbl)
# [1] 1
dbGetQuery(db, paste("select count(*) as n from", tbl))
#    n
# 1 11
maybe_add_row_sql(my_data_base[1,], db, tbl, tmptbl)
# [1] 0
dbGetQuery(db, paste("select count(*) as n from", tbl))
#    n
# 1 11
```

Okay, we can run this at scale now.

```r
print(dbGetQuery(db, paste("select count(*) as n from", tbl)))
#    n
# 1 11
system.time({
  for (i in 1:100) {
    new_data <-
      if (runif(1) < 0.1) {
        message("forcing a dupe!")
        my_data_base[sample(nrow(my_data_base), 1),]
      } else make_dat(nrow=1, ncol=5)
    res <- maybe_add_row_sql(new_data, db, tbl, tmptbl)
    if (!res) message(".. not inserted")
  }
})
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
# forcing a dupe!
# .. not inserted
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.780   0.036   0.892 
print(dbGetQuery(db, paste("select count(*) as n from", tbl)))
#     n
# 1 100
```

Much faster. We can confirm that there are no dupes with a quick simple query:

```r
dbGetQuery(db, "with cte as (select name, count(*) as n from mydata group by name, v1) select * from cte where n > 1")
# [1] name n   
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

You can query the data you want directly,

```r
dbGetQuery(db, "select * from mydata where name like '%a%'")
#   name    v1    v2    v3    v4    v5
# 1  7aE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# 2  sau  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# 3  8ah FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# 4  oaf  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# 5  Ya3  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

and you can still use `dplyr` if you prefer:

```r
tbl(db, tbl) %>%
  filter(grepl("a", name)) %>%
  collect()
# # A tibble: 5 × 6
#   name  v1    v2    v3    v4    v5   
#   <chr> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
# 1 7aE   FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
# 2 sau   TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
# 3 8ah   FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE
# 4 oaf   TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE 
# 5 Ya3   TRUE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Still not all ready into memory. See https://solutions.posit.co/connections/db/r-packages/dplyr/ for more info on `dplyr` and databases.

Don't stop here ... we did this row-by-row, but if you're creating multiple rows at once, this still works without change.

```r
new_data <- rbind(make_dat(nrow=10, ncol=5), my_data_base[1:2,])
dbGetQuery(db, paste("select count(*) as n from", tbl))
#     n
# 1 100
maybe_add_row_sql(new_data, db, tbl, tmptbl)
# [1] 10
dbGetQuery(db, paste("select count(*) as n from", tbl))
#     n
# 1 110
```

Note that `new_data` had 12 rows (with 2 known dupes) and only 10 new rows were added.

Comment: Hello! Sorry, I probably didn't formulate my question clearly.

My question was about:
How can I do what I do but on the condition that 'my_data_base' is so large that it does not fit in RAM

Comment: Yeah, that's not even remotely in your question. Are you talking database, arrow/parquet, or some other not-in-memory processing?

Comment: Any tool that can do this in R

Comment: Okay @mr.T, take a look. (I should charge for the time it took to draft and work through that ;-)

Comment: The DB approach with anti_join looks good. (Not sure if there's a way to skip collect() below, which is not elegant.)

old_data <- tbl(db, "old_data");
to_write <- new_data |> copy_to(db, df = _) |> anti_join(old_data) |> collect();
dbWriteTable(db, to_write, "old_table", append = TRUE)

Comment: The OP's understated requirement was that the operations be done without all or most of the data in memory, the use of `dbWriteTable` (and yes, due to the `collect()` as you mentioned) defeats that premise. It certainly looks elegant, I don't know of a way to do something akin to `anti_join(..) %>% db_write_table(..)` without its `table=` needing to be in memory, though perhaps `dbplyr` supports it? @IanGow

Comment: The `collect()` would only need to apply to the incremental new data (`to_write`). Ideally, one could just `db_write_table(..., append = TRUE)` with server-side data, but this appears unsupported (at least in DuckDB's `dbplyr`).

Comment: Actually, `rows_append(old_data_db, to_write, in_place = TRUE)` does the trick without `collect()`. See https://gist.github.com/iangow/e907d7543a05b8a713d8ea2030806b22 for an illustration.

Comment: @r2evans See above for some good news.